# Blank window doesn't close automatically after download file

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron application that opens an external page.
Inside this page, I have a button to download a file.
On a normal browser, when I click the download button, it opens a _blank tab and start the download automatically, and immediately closes the tab.
But, on Electron application, the _blank tab opens a new Window and ask for download location and the window don't close automatically, as desired.

How can I reproduce the "normal" browser behaviour on Electron?

The code to download the file is:
`window.open(url, '_blank', '');`

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you replace your code to download the file with a dummy link element:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = url;
a.download = "filename";
a.click();
```

Does that result in the same behavior or could it be an acceptable workaround?

EDIT: Or perhaps even simpler; replace your download button with a link (that you can style as a button):

```
<a href="your-data-uri" download="filename">
```

Comment: I tried this solution and worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can reversibly retrieve the browser window instance for that blank window, see

```
import { BrowserWindow } from 'electron'

//...
  mainWindow.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
     item.once('done', (event, state) => {
        BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(webcontents).close();
     }); 
  });
```

here is the doc link: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#browserwindowfromwebcontentswebcontents

---

BTW, the answer from @vegard-løkken is not ideal, since [`download` property complies with the same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I faced the same scenario only recently and came up with the below solution:

```
 mainWindow.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
     item.once('done', (event, state) => {
        var wins = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
        for(var i=0;i<wins.length;i++){
           //avoid closing the main window
           if(wins[i].id !=1){
              wins[i].close();
           }           
        }
     }); 
  });
```